# How to render html code in @Html.TextBox asp .Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

Hi I'm creating MVC application and I'm using tinyMCE. Sometimes i need to change tinyMCE with simple TextBox field. I'm trying this with hide and show. At the begging I'm showing TextArea and hidding TextBox, but when user click convert tinyMCE to simple textBox field, I'm hidding textArea and showing TextBox.
This is my tinyMCE field

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.supTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

and this is simple TextBox

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.supTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

but when I'm using TextBoxFor I have something like this

```
<p> some text</p>
```

but I want only `some text` to be displayed without `<p>` tags.
Also when I save the changes only the changes from TextArea are saves into database.

Comment: force_p_newlines: false ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but: does your `htmlAttributes` declaration need to be on its own, rather than in a new anon' object? Like this: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.supTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`?

Comment: You cannot generate 2 form controls with the same `name` attribute and have it bind to your model - the `DefaultModelBinder` only bindes the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If the value stored in the `model.supTitle` property contains Html as a string you would have to parse out the html before rendering the value to a standard `input[type=text]`.

Only the first value is persisted to the database because both form elements have the same name, when the form is posted both values will be sent in the Http Post but the MVC model binding will only map the first form value to the model (which in this case is the text area).

Hiding & showing a html element does not prevent the value of the element from being posted in a form post, you would need to either remove the element from the DOM altogether or change the element name so that it is not bound by the model binder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your view

```
@Html.Raw(Model.YourTinyMCEContent);
```